# Including or loading a php depending on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu, php-include

I would like to dynamically include different php files, containing a form (which is different for any entry in the dropdown), while changing a dropdown .

Even using jQuery would be ok.
I read that jQuery works client side, while php server side, so looking for an alternative.
basically I would like to have something like this code.

If value of the dropdown is 1 then include file1.php, if it is 2, then include file2.php, and this before pressing a button, but only while changing the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using AJAX, using the `onChange` option on a dropdown (select) run a ajax request. Check which ajax file to load using the select value and display it.

Here is a quick how-to on ajax, 
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Ajax can update a page without reloading it.